# Chapter number font size

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I borrowed this code from [Clean Thesis](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template with a small modification in color selection.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-8.75em}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace*{2.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \ctchapternumber{\thechapter}%
}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ctchaptertitle{#3}%
    #2%
}

\newcommand{\ctchapternumber}[1]{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}%
        \raggedleft{%
            {\color{red!50!black}\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
            \quad%
            {\color{red!50!black}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont#1}%
        }%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\newcommand{\ctchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}%
        \vspace*{5.85em}%
        \raggedright%
        #1%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This is the result I get.

[image]

As you can see, I already used font size 60 for chapter number but It doesn't get any bigger. It seems `\fontsize{60}{60}` has no effect on the chapter number font size. How do fix this?

Comment: There is a fontfeature called scale ...   you can \addfontfeatures for some fonts.... Not sure if this is what you are looking for.   Check the fontspec package for the syntax you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/n' in size <60> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 36.
```

So you have to use a scalable font like `lmodern`.

Additional remark: Do not redefine `\chapterstartvskip` and `\chapterendvskip`, use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` with option `afterindent=false` instead.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% added

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=-8.75em,
  afterskip=2.5\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \ctchapternumber{\thechapter}%
}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ctchaptertitle{#3}%
    #2%
}

\newcommand{\ctchapternumber}[1]{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}%
        \raggedleft{%
            {\color{red!50!black}\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
            \quad%
            {\color{red!50!black}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont#1}%
        }%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\newcommand{\ctchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}%
        \vspace*{5.85em}%
        \raggedright%
        #1%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}



\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ifoot{Test}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\Huge}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[%
    main=ngerman,
    %english,
    british,
    american,
    french,
]{babel}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]